# How to call a simple stored procedure in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I just want to call the stored procedure from ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC.

I see this type of question many times but every question containing some parameters or calling any by the individual table.

But nothing that is in use for me.

Because just I want to call the stored procedure so the whole function will be done by the stored procedure only.

But I am don't know how to call special stored procedure by the controller.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbbackup
    @BackupSQLScript nvarchar(max),
    @SQLBackupFileName nvarchar(max),
    @DatabaseName sysname,
    @SQLBackupFolder nvarchar(400)
as 
begin
    set @DatabaseName = 'SQL Database'
    set @SQLBackupFolder = 'D:\'

    set @SQLBackupFileName = replace(@DatabaseName, ' ', '-') + convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) + '.bak'

    set @BackupSQLScript = 'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @DatabaseName + ']
                            TO DISK = ''' + @SQLBackupFolder + @SQLBackupFileName + ''''

    print @BackupSQLScript

    exec sp_executesql @BackupSQLScript
end
```

Just I call this stored procedure from the controller.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database (i.e. Entity Framework, Dapper, etc)?  What have you tried? You posted SQL but didn't post any C# code.

Answer (score 1):

First Create a class with empty body, but .Net Core may complain about the class not having a primary key so you can add one property decorated with `[Key]`

```
public class simple {
  [Key]
  public int nothing {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your dbContext class add it to your DbSet  declarations

```
public virtual DbSet<simple> Simple { get; set; }
```

Then in your controller, you simply do this

```
public IActionResult SimpleProcedure()
{
   var q = dbcontext.Simple.FromSql("exec dbBackup");
   return OK(q);
}
```